# Create a smart-pointer-to-base-class from a reference

Tags: c++

I have a container which store a vector of smart-pointer-to-base-class, and I'd like to populate it via a method *without* requiring my users to also create that smart pointer:

```cpp
class Base {
    // ...
};
class Derived: public Base {
    // ... 
};

class Collection {
private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> pointers;

public:
    void add(Base&& value) // #1
    {
        pointers.push_back(????);  
    }

    void add<typename T>(T&& value) // #2
    {
        pointers.push_back(????);
    }
};

int main() {
    Collection collection;
    collection.add(Derived("Data"));  // #3
}
```

What's the correct way to do this, if at all? It's clear that I could use `make_unique` and emplacement, except that I'm concerned that the derived content won't be moved correctly.

It's possible I've spent too much time in Rust land, where moves of this kind are pretty commonplace, so let me know if I'm way off base here. Ideally, the interface looks like my #3 point up there, where the function can be called with a literal of the derived type without any extra boilerplate related to allocation or anything. I'd be find if the solution ends up being to make `Collection::add` generic.

Comment: You cannot move an object with automatic storage duration into a smart pointer - you'd have to create a copy of it that is dynamically allocated

Comment: One approach is to add a virtual clone method to the base class and all derived classes will need to override it

Comment: @UnholySheep presumably there's no (idiomatic) way to create that copy? That is, this is the "no virtual copy constructors" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably stick to the template, yes. You then get

```
class Collection {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> pointers;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(T &&value) {
        pointers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(value)));
    }
};

int main() {
    Collection c;
    Derived d;
    c.add(d); // works with lvalues (copying)
    c.add(std::move(d)); // or rvalues (moving)
    Base b;
    c.add(b);
    c.add(std::move(b));
}
```

However, it might be more useful to provide an "emplace", which constructs an object out of arbitrary arguments (as provided by all the standard containers)

```
class Collection {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> pointers;

public:
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void emplace(Ts&&... args) {
        pointers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
    }
    template<typename T> // still useful for conciseness (don't have to specify T)
    void add(T &&value) {
        this->emplace<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
};
```

So you can further do

```
int main() {
    Collection c;
    Derived d;
    c.add(d); // works with lvalues
    c.add(std::move(d)); // or rvalues
    c.emplace<Derived>(); // or can give arguments directly (assuming a default constructor, in this case)
    Base b;
    c.add(b);
    c.add(std::move(b));
    c.emplace<Base>();
}
```

[A complete example on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/n2fYCH)